# I Can't Extract the Tinycore core.gz File

Tags: linux, windows, windows-11, gunzip, tiny-core-linux

I am modifying tinycore, the core only version, after extracting the ISO file with 7Zip, and I can't extract the core.gz file for some reason. In the Windows 11 Explorer Extractor, it says I don't hold some privileges for most of the files. Same with 7Zip. I have even tried a ton of extracting websites, but they all fail too. I don't have admin on my computer, but I am not trying to put it anywhere that would need admin, and am putting it in my downloads folder. Can someone please help me?